# Understanding Secure Email

Tags: email, ssl, ssl-certificate, security

I've got a question about securing emails with SSL.

If I get an SSL certificate to secure my email, that would mean that the connection between my mail client and my mail server will be encrypted. So anyone listening in couldn't view my emails or username and password. But what happens between the mail server and the destination mail server? And between there and the recipient's mail client? If the reciepient isn't using SSL, will the email and it's contents still be secure?

Also, out of interest, is the danger of people "listening in" just from your internal network (people using packet sniffers) or is there a danger of people out in the cloud listening in?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This only secures the connection/communication between your mail client and the mail server.

So people on your internal network can't sniff (at least not in clear text) your mail.

How the transport between the mail server from your server to the server of the recipient happens depends on their configuration.

Basically you can't avoid the risk of some mail server operator reading your mail, or the NSA reading it, and so on...

The only thing to secure your mail against a malicious mail server operator would be to encrypt your mail with some [Public-key cryptography system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) (e.g. PGP).

Comment: Fun fact.  Over 80% of the email servers in the world route their email through the united states for no technical reason whatsoever.

You know though, so few people actually encrypt their emails that encrypting your email is basically putting a flag on it saying decrypt this.  Email is not secure, you need a document or comms to be secured you need to catch a plane with an encrypted document or file and give it to who you wan to have it.

Comment: Well the flag which says "decrypt me" doesn't bother me. As decrypting a strongly encrypted mail is still not feasible

Comment: Thanks for your response Jitter! It's cleared my understanding of secure email up! It's a shame all email's so unsecure! Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Only the connection between your client (if correctly configured) and your server will be encrypted (same for the recipients end), once the email leaves your server on its way to your recipients mailserver it will be open for all to see.

Ie. You (using SSL) -> SECURE -> Your Server -> UNSECURE -> Internet -> UNSECURE -> Recipient's Server -> SECURE -> Recipient (using SSL).

To ensure secure delivery the email needs to be encrypted end-to-end (ie. the actual contents of the email - rather than just the delivery to/from the server). This can be done through several differnt mechanism (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_encryption) for a list) one of the more common ones is using [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) for email (see [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=pgp+email) for more).

There is a risk of people listening in on both the internal network and in the cloud, the probabilities of eitehr i am not sure on but i would say the internal network would generally be the more liekly location of a 'listener'.

Answer (score 1):

> If I get an SSL certificate to secure
>   my email, that would mean that the
>   connection between my mail client and
>   my mail server will be encrypted.

No. But it would mean that it's possible to establish an encrypted connection to your server.

> But what happens between the mail
>   server and the destination mail
>   server? And between there and the
>   recipient's mail client? If the
>   reciepient isn't using SSL, will the
>   email and it's contents still be
>   secure?

No. All you get from SSL-encrypting the connection to your server is the encrypted login dialog so attackers won't be able to look at your username/password.

If you want to protect your mail messages, you will have to encrypt them in the mail client. [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) and [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smime) come to mind.