# Is yahoo/google/etc. account name visible to my office administrator?

Tags: email, https

The fact that I access a certain website is certainly visible to the admin in my office - i.e. at work - and to the ISPs at work, home or wherever I access that website from. But if I send an e-mail from Yahoo/Google/etc. are the sender and receiver visible to the said admin, considering the fact that the connection is thru https: ?

Comment: Here is a possible answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995178/understanding-secure-email. Quite unexpected and disappointing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about using email services are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things to consider here:

1. **Connecting to your service prover** If you log on to https://mail.google.com or https://www.hotmail.com then you are over https and so **should** be secure.

   However most corporates only have internet access through a proxy and like to virus scan traffic. As HTTPS traffic is encrypted they use so called man in the middle (MITM) proxies so when you connect to Gmail over https you actual connect to the proxy over https (and it provides a HTTPS certificate in Google's name) and then that proxy connects to Google.

   This is allowed by web browsers if the proxy certificate is set up as a local CA on your computer (which if in such a corporate environment they will be able to install this), but is very difficult to do without access to your machine (e.g.on coffee shop wifi as you will get a HTTPS certificate error). While this sounds dodgy (and is not well liked by security professionals as can introduce more risks), it is quite common in larger companies - though often companies that do this also block access to web mail providers as well. Virus scanners installed on your machine work in the exact same way.

   You can see if this is the case by looking at the HTTPS certificate change in your browser and see if it is the same as at home and chains up to a real certificate authority (CA) or to your company name.

   Once a party is performing a MITM and, while most companies have neither the resources nor the inclination to read this traffic, other than to run it through an automatic virus scanner, in theory they can.
2. **Encryption to the sender address.** Once you are on your mail provider (via web mail or from an email client on your device) and send a mail, for example from your gmail account to a hotmail account you've got to consider whether that connection is encrypted. [In 2026 Gmail started warning if the sender address is for a service that doesn't allow Gmail to use HTTPS to send it the message](https://blog.google/products/gmail/making-email-safer-for-you-posted-by/). Unfortunately that was pretty much the norm for a long time and [in 2014 Google said 50% of mail it sends is unencrypted](https://googleblog.blogspot.ie/2014/06/transparency-report-protecting-emails.html?m=1), though (partially in response to Gmail marking this as insecure I guess) [that has increased to 80% at the time of writing](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/saferemail/).

   Either way this is from Gmail servers so local admins (e.g. in your office) should not be able to intercept this traffic as it's not sent on the local network (unless you work for a network telco or a spy agency!), but in theory unencrypted messages could be read here.
3. **User encrypted mail only encrypted the body.** Technologies like PGP or SMIME allow you to Encrypt your email message separately before you send it via a provider but this is only for the message contents so the To Address, From Address and Subject are still visible over plain text SMIME does allow you to have different subjects but that has its own problems - [see the answer here for more details](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83714/what-are-the-security-differences-between-smime-email-and-pgp-email)). And it's a massive of a pain to use these to be honest.
4. **Authentication technologies like do not help here** When researching encrypted mail you may see mention of DMARC, DKIM and SPF but they are authentication methods (to ensure **you** sent the message) rather than tools to hide data so ignore any mention of those when asking about hiding data. For example [the earlier Google Blog link](https://blog.google/products/gmail/making-email-safer-for-you-posted-by/) talks about authentication as the other thing they will warn against.

Quote a broad topic, and not a great fit for a Stack Overflow question to be honest (perhaps would be OK on the sister site http://security.stackexchange.com), but hopefully that gives you some understanding anyway.

Comment: Thanks++ for the answer. PS. Is StackExchange better suited for questions not related to programming ?

Comment: StackExchange is the parent site of StackOverflow and includes several different subsites for different types of questions - some as subdomains like the security one, and some as separate domains like StackOverflow. StackOverflow is the original and most popular but should only be used for programming question. Problem is finding which StackExchange site your question really belongs on!

Comment: Thanks again. I imagine the list of (sub)domains to be quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Another, more detailed answer, can be found here: [Using SSL/TSL to secure your communications](https://luxsci.com/blog/how-does-secure-socket-layer-ssl-or-tls-work.html). What I understand summing up both answers is that the e-mail content should be encrypted separately to be completely safe. I still am not sure what the answer is re: e-mail adresses of the sender and the receiver(s).